# when i started mongodb db.runCommand...host already used error invoked~

Tags: mongodb

```
db.runCommand({addshard:"localhost:10000"});
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "host already used" }
db.runCommand( { addshard : "localhost:10001" } );
{ "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "host already used" }
```

how can i solve that problem? it is "host already used" error

please give me a tips to solve this~

Answer (score 3):

According to mongodb [source code](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/fd600969e0eccdfce48bb93fadaecc5daed64129/s/grid.cpp) this message say that you've already added this specified host:port as a shard:

```
// check whether this host:port is not an already a known shard
BSONObj old = conn->findOne( ShardNS::shard , BSON( "host" << host ) );
if ( ! old.isEmpty() ){
   *errMsg = "host already used";
   conn.done();
   return false;
}
```

You can use `listShards` command to see your current shards:

```
db.runCommand( { listshards : 1 } );
```

Comment: In the js shell run `sh.status()` and it should give you information about your shard status.